# Javascript Logical Operator AND inside 'if' condition

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

Inside the `if` condition, I have `num1` and `num2` which are checked to see if they can be divided by 2 to determine whether they are odd or not. As you can see, I am checking to see if when divided by 2, whether the answer is 0 or not for both `num1` and `num2`. I'm not sure why it evaluates to `true` when I enter `num2` argument as an even number.

```
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
  if(num1 % 2 === 0 && num2 % 2 === 0){
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}

var output = areBothOdd(7, 4);
console.log(output); // --> true
```

Why am I getting `true`?

And why does this code evaluate as false?

```
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
  if(num1 % 2 !== 0 && num2 % 2 !== 0){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

var output = areBothOdd(7, 4);
console.log(output); // --> false
```

Comment: Because that's correct, you've got your modulus division confused.

Comment: `return num1 % 2 && num2 % 2;`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a logical OR `||`, instead of an logical AND.

Your test with

```
num1 % 2 === 0
```

returns `true` for even numbers, because even numbers have a remainder of `0` by division with `2`.

```js
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
    if (num1 % 2 === 0 || num2 % 2 === 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

console.log(areBothOdd(7, 4)); // --> false
console.log(areBothOdd(7, 5)); // --> true
console.log(areBothOdd(4, 4)); // --> false
```

For a check with logical AND, you need to negate the parts and change the logical operator from OR to AND, as the [De_Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) describes the transformation.

```
num1 % 2 === 0 || num2 % 2 === 0    both parts 
num1 % 2 !== 0 && num2 % 2 !== 0    are equal
         ^^^^  ^^          ^^^
```

```js
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
    if (num1 % 2 !== 0 && num2 % 2 !== 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

console.log(areBothOdd(7, 4)); // --> false
console.log(areBothOdd(7, 5)); // --> true
console.log(areBothOdd(4, 4)); // --> false
```

Answer (score 0):

It always evaluate to true because, **what && operator does is to check both condition, if both condition is true than the block will get executed, otherwise else block will get executed.**

**% will return remainder which will never be zero. in your case while calculate modules** i.e 7%2 will result 1.
either you need to use logical !! operator or you can change your condition.

```js
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
  if(num1 % 2 === 0 && num2 % 2 === 0){
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}

var output = areBothOdd(7, 4);
console.log(output);
```

```js
var x = 7%2;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Comment: Why will the remainder never be zero?

Comment: _The remainder will never be zero_ What is 2 % 2, 4 % 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because of [Short-Circuit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) evaluation. Simply put, your `num2 % 2 === 0` part of condition will not be evaluated. `7 % 2` does not equal to zero hence your function returns `true`. That's it.

To quote from MDN:

> - false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.
> - true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true.
>
> Note that the anything part of the above expressions is not evaluated,
>   so any side effects of doing so do not take effect

Answer (score 0):

**1st Case :**

```js
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
  if(num1 % 2 === 0 && num2 % 2 === 0){
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}

var output = areBothOdd(7, 4);
console.log(output); // --> true
```

Here, `if condition` fails as `(num1 % 2 === 0 && num2 % 2 === 0)` will become `(false && true)` as 7 is an odd number and 4 is an even number.Hence, it will execute the `else` block and return `true`.

**2nd Case :**

```js
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
  if(num1 % 2 !== 0 && num2 % 2 !== 0){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}

var output = areBothOdd(7, 4);
console.log(output); // --> false
```

Here again `if condition` fails as `(num1 % 2 !== 0 && num2 % 2 !== 0)` will become (true && false).Hence, it will execute the `else` block and return `false`.

**Conclusion :** As [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) suggested, use `logical OR(||)` instead of an `logical AND(&&)`.

**DEMO**

```js
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
  if(num1 % 2 === 0 || num2 % 2 === 0){
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
}

var output = areBothOdd(7, 4);
console.log(output); // --> false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can change the if condition.In this case,if num1 is odd it doesnot satisfy the if condition and therefore returns true which is else condition.
You can try something like this.
function areBothOdd(int num1,int num2){
    if(num1%2 !==0){
        if(num2%2!==0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure why it evaluates to `true` when I enter `num2` argument as an even number. Why am I getting true?

There are three possible conditions to consider:

1. both are odd,
2. both are even, or
3. one is odd and one is even

Your first example checks condition 2 (both even) and returns `false` only for this. Condition 1 and 3 are captured by the `else` statement and both return `true` (which is not what you want, you want condition 3 to return `false`). When providing the numbers `7` and `4`, this corresponds to condition 3, which illustrates how the function fails.

> And why does this code evaluate as false?

Your second example gets it right, it checks for condition 1 (both odd), and returns `true`. Otherwise, for condition 2 and 3 it returns `false`, which is what you want.

Your first code example commented:

```js
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
  if(num1 % 2 === 0 && num2 % 2 === 0){ // if both are even
    return false;
  }
  else { // otherwise, if one is even or both are odd
    return true;
  }
}

var output = areBothOdd(7, 4); // one number is even
console.log(output); // --> true
```

(Note that `num % 2 === 0` is a way to test for an even number, and `num % 2 !== 0`, `num % 2`, or `num & 1` are ways to test for an odd number.)

With a few small changes, the function will work as intended (corresponds to your code example 2):

```js
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
  if(num1 % 2 && num2 % 2){ // if both are odd
    return true;
  }
  else { // otherwise, if one is even or both are even
    return false;
  }
}

var output = areBothOdd(7, 4); // one number is even
console.log(output); // --> false
```

Or just simply:

```
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
  return num1 & 1 && num2 & 1
}
```

Demo code and tests:

```js
function areBothOdd(num1, num2) {
  if(num1 % 2 && num2 % 2){ // if both are odd
    return true;
  }
  else { // otherwise, if one is even or both are even
    return false;
  }
}

// tests

test(1, 1, true);  // both are odd
test(2, 2, false); // none are odd
test(1, 2, false); // only one is odd
test(2, 1, false); // only one is odd

// test function

function test(num1, num2, expected) {
  console.log(
    areBothOdd(num1, num2) == expected ? 
      'Passes' : 'Fails'
  )
}
```